# Is there shortcut to auto organize imports and formatting in xcode?

Tags: xcode

In Android Studio, we could

1. Auto organize import (remove unused import and sort them), using `Control+Option+o`
2. Auto format the code (e.g. remove additional spaces in a statement), using `Option+Command+l`.

Is there the same/similar Short+Cut in Xcode that does the above two?

(I know `Control+i` will readjust the indent, but just the indent, but not removing other additional spaces in the code).

Comment: I don't think there is anything for imports and I haven't found anything else for formatting

Comment: [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) can do some automatic corrections